# Site icons in the Super Collider are not SVG format

Tags: bug, design, stack-exchange-button, favicon

Recently, lots of images became SVG, for example the Inbox and the Achievements icons.

However, the Super Collider site favicons are their usual blurry selves:

[image]

Note that the SE logo in the top bar is fine:

[image]

Could the favicons be vectorised?